# Arithmetic operations on dates in python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I want to know how many days is there between two dates in python, I'm using type "date" to store information. But if I just subtract two dates, I receive not an integer value, but some kind of tuple:

```
from datetime import *

a = date(2016, 9, 26)
b = date(2017, 1, 25)
delta = b - a

print('Interval is', delta, 'days long.')
```

Returns: `Interval is 121 days, 0:00:00 days long.`

But if I do it this way, I receive the number of days only.

```
from datetime import *

a = date(2016, 9, 26)
b = date(2017, 1, 25)

delta = b - a

print('Interval is', delta.days, 'days long.\n')
```

Returns: `Interval is 121 long.`

[In Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) for version 3.6 object of class "date" has 3 arguments:

```
class datetime.date(year, month, day)
```

Why it still returns unnecessary time `0:00:00` delta when operating on dates itself?

Comment: What do you mean "unnecessary"?

Comment: I mean `0:00:00`, if a type date, has only years, months and days why adding time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, now I get it! Subtraction does not return integer value with number of days, it returns object of type `timedelta`, and in this particular case you then have to explicitly access values by `delta.days` and `delta.miliseconds`.

Comment: Sorry about that, it just occurred to me moment after I clicked "post" :) but thanks, anyway!